# How can I check if a box is alive or down using the ip address in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ping a site in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

I'm wondering how are you able to do this?

Comment: See this question: [Ping a site in Python? (Stack Overflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)