# HTTPS connection Python

Tags: python, ssl, https, httplib, pyopenssl

I am trying to verify the that target exposes a https web service. I have code to connect via HTTP but I am not sure how to connect via HTTPS. I have read you use SSL but I have also read that it did not support certificate errors. The code I have got is from the python docs:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason
```

Does anyone know how to connect to HTTPS?

I already tried the HTTPSConenction but it responds with an error code claiming httplib does not have attribute HTTPSConnection. I also don't have socket.ssl available.

I have installed Python 2.6.4 and I don't think it has SSL support compiled into it. Is there a way to integrate this suppot into the newer python without having to install it again.

I have installed OpenSSL and pyOpenSsl and I have tried the below code from one of the answers:

```
import urllib2
from OpenSSL import SSL
try: 
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://example.com')  
    print 'response headers: "%s"' % response.info() 
except IOError, e: 
    if hasattr(e, 'code'): # HTTPError 
        print 'http error code: ', e.code 
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'): # URLError 
        print "can't connect, reason: ", e.reason 
    else: 
        raise
```

I have got an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/build/workspace/downloads/Python-2.6.4/Lib/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/home/build/workspace/downloads/Python-2.6.4/Lib/urllib.py", line 203, in open
    return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
  File "/home/build/workspace/downloads/Python-2.6.4/Lib/urllib.py", line 215, in open_unknown
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'unknown url type', type)
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: 'https'
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

```
-- UPDATE
```

I have found out what the problem was, the Python version I was using did not have support for SSL. I have found this solution currently at: http://www.webtop.com.au/compiling-python-with-ssl-support.

The code will now work after this solution which is very good. When I import ssl and HTTPSConnection I know don't get an error.

Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Python 2.x: [docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html):

> Note: HTTPS support is only available if the socket module was compiled with SSL support.

Python 3.x: [docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html):

> Note HTTPS support is only available if Python was compiled with SSL support (through the ssl module).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("ccc.de")
c.request("GET", "/")
response = c.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
# => 
# 200 OK
# <!DOCTYPE html ....
```

To verify if SSL is enabled, try:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.ssl
<function ssl at 0x4038b0>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't verify the remote certificate, therefore you don't really get security this way (as you don't really know which server you're really talking to).

Comment: Wrong url in tequest

Comment: how to check IP with this response ?

Answer (score 14):

To check for [ssl support in Python 2.6+](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html):

```
try:
    import ssl
except ImportError:
    print "error: no ssl support"
```

To connect via [https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935939/python-send-cmd-on-socket/1936923#1936923):

```
import urllib2

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://example.com') 
    print 'response headers: "%s"' % response.info()
except IOError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'): # HTTPError
        print 'http error code: ', e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'): # URLError
        print "can't connect, reason: ", e.reason
    else:
        raise
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com") 
data = r.content  # Content of response

print r.status_code  # Status code of response
print data
```

Comment: @notilas, this code does work.  If you just print `r`, you will get a string version of the response object itself rather than the content of the response, which is what you typed above, `<Resposne [200]>`.  That is simply saying that the request was successful (200 is the HTTP code for success).  Try looking at `r.content` or `r.text` (or `r.json()` if you're content is JSON) to get the actual result of the request.

Comment: @bjg222 Thanks for kind explanation.

Answer (score 9):

using

```
class httplib.HTTPSConnection
```

http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection

Answer (score 6):

If using **httplib.HTTPSConnection:**

Please take a look at:

> [Changed in version 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection):
>
> This class now performs all the necessary certificate and hostname
>   checks by default. To revert to the previous, unverified, behavior
>   ssl._create_unverified_context() can be passed to the context
>   parameter. You can use:

```
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
  ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score 5):

Why haven't you tried httplib.HTTPSConnection? It doesn't do SSL validation but this isn't required to connect over https.
Your code works fine with https connection:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("mail.google.com")
>>> conn.request("GET", "/")
>>> r1 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r1.status, r1.reason
200 OK
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SSL support is enabled for the `socket` module.

```
connection1 = httplib.HTTPSConnection('www.somesecuresite.com')
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some code that was failing with an `HTTPConnection (MOVED_PERMANENTLY error)`, but as soon as I switched to `HTTPS` it worked perfectly again with no other changes needed.  That's a very simple fix!

Comment: How is this different compared to other answers? Maybe try to elaborate a bit more.