# HTTPS certificate verification using corporate Certification Authority in Python

Tags: python, ssl, https, certificate

I need to make a HTTPS call to a server with a certificate signed by our corporate authority. How do I configure python to trust this certificate authority?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS connection Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146383/https-connection-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate SSL certificates with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python)

Comment: This isn't how to make https/ssl but how to add a trusted authority

Answer (score 0):

By default (assuming you're using `httplib.HTTPSConnection`), you don't have to do anything, this [`httplib` doesn't do any certificate verification](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) (the [same applies to `urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)).

Of course, this is not a good this and you should verify the server certificate. There are various solutions to this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python)).

In short, you may have to extend `httplib.HTTPConnection` to turn the socket into an SSL socket via `ssl.wrap_socket` manually, so as to be able to insert the verification callbacks (you'll need to verify both the host name and the certificates).

Alternatively, if you're not constrained to `httplib`, using [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) would certainly make this cleaner. You can configure `CA_INFO` (or `CA_PATH`) to point to your internal CA certificate. In addition, it usually doesn't come with a pre-defined list of CAs, but you can get one from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) (converted from the Mozilla list) and add these certificates to the list of CAs you trust if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for sample code to solve this, here it is in [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/):

```
import pycurl
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "https://your-secure-website.com/")
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)
curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, "/path/to/your-corporate-certificate-chain.crt")
curl.perform()
```

Make sure to place the your-corporate-certificate-chain.crt file in an accessible location and use the pycurl.CAINFO option to point to it.