# Python httplib disble certificate validation

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have the following code to use:

```
def createCon(host,auth):
    con = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
    return con
def _readJson(con,url):
    con.putrequest("GET",url)
    ...
    r = con.getresponse()
```

It is working on a specific server, but on another I'm getting SSLError. If I open the url from browser, I need to accept the certificate and it is working well. But how can I either accept the certificate or disable it's validation? This is a self-signed certificate stored in a java keystore, so I would prefer to disable the verification...
The code is meant to reuse the connection between the requests, so I would prefer not to modify it deeply.

How could I do this? I tried to modify the examples but haven't beend succeded.

```
con.putrequest("GET",url, verify=False)
or
con.request.verify=False
```

I do not know how could I access the session or request objects or modify the default settings.

**UPDATE** this does not help:

```
socket.ssl.cert_reqs='CERT_NONE'
```

well, the actual error message is weird...:

```
SSLError:'[Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group'
```

Regards:
   Bence

Comment: Strange, are you sure the socket module was compiled with SSL support? If you want to test it try:
```>>> import socket```

```>>> socket.ssl```

```<function ssl at 0x4038b0>```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2146467/664470

Comment: SSL checked: <function ssl at 0x7ff9c681ec08>, I already read that answer. Well, this is python 2.6.6 and it seems it does validation.

Comment: Thanks for the error message, it helps. What Operating System do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message points to a bug in the openssl version you use. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468. In short: the client advertises capabilities it does not have and if the server picks such capability you get this error message. Needs to be fixed by upgrading your local openssl installation. A workaround on the server side should be possible too, if you have control over the server.

Comment: Yes, thanks. After openssl upgrade it seems to be fine.