# loading https page into wx.html.HTMLWindow

Tags: python, ssl, https, wxwidgets, wxhtmlwindow

I am trying to load a https url into an HTMLWindow

```
import wx
import wx.html

class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(600,400))
        html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        if "gtk2" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            html.SetStandardFonts()

        wx.CallAfter(html.LoadPage, "https://www.google.com")#Fails to load page 
        #but the following works ...
        #wx.CallAfter(html.LoadPage, "http://www.google.com")#Works Fine!


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frm = MyHtmlFrame(None, "Simple HTML Browser")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Is there a way to load a ssl page in HTMLWindow (or some other in-a-wxWindow way to render ssl pages)?

I am using wx 2.8.10 , and upgrading is not really an option currently

Comment: Can you use [`WebView`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html) instead?

Comment: unfortunately not unless there is a python package that just gives me that (I am using 2.8.10, and that isnt around until 2.9.3, and cant really update...)

Comment: @lmjohns3 thanks for the inspiration it looks like iewin will work fine, which is somewhat simillar (since im on windows ... I would rather make something more portable but meh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wanted to grant my bounty to someone but really here is the solution that lmjohns led me too ... sort of ... the solution is to use `wx IEWin`

```
import wx
import wx.lib.iewin as iewin
class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.browser =  iewin.IEHtmlWindow(self)
    sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.SetSize((850, 730))
  def load(self,uri):
      self.browser.Navigate(uri)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App()
  dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
  dialog.browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
  dialog.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just download the file using an existing method like `urllib2.urlopen`, and save the file to the filesystem and then pass that filename to the LoadPage method of HtmlWindow.

Examples of existing methods are covered in the following StackOverflow questions, [HTTPS connection Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146383/https-connection-python)  and [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Other options that are more complicated involve using wxIE and wxMozilla, once your have downloaded or compiled the Python bindings.

Comment: wxIE comes builtin ... I cannot just download, since the page I actually need to talk to is a form that needs to be submitted +1 for the suggestion all the same :)