# How can I create https connection on python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, httplib

#### The situation

I'm trying to connect to a server on https protocol with python script. Could someone give me the working example that sends a GET request to https server, or web resource to how to create https connection with python?

#### An attempt so far

I have learned that the module httplib on python supports creation of http connection, but not https connection?

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('https://adsche.skplanet.com/api/startNewTurn')
header = {"Content-type" : "application/json"}
conn.request('GET', '/announce?info_hash=%da', '', header)
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason
data1 = r1.read()
print data1
```

Comment: Are you familiar with  `httplib.HTTPSConnection()`?

Comment: I've never heard of it. But I'll check it if needed to create https connection.

Comment: But I prefer the working example to web resource because I am poor at english. So, I would be grateful if someone gives me the working exmaple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS connection Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146383/https-connection-python)