# Python - get HTML from HTTPS url - socket module does not have ssl enabled?

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu, ssl

I am trying to get the html for a website, but the site uses https not http.

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("google.com")
c.request("GET", "/")
response = c.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
```

according to [HTTPS connection Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146383/https-connection-python) the socket module needs to be compiled with ssl or have ssl enabled.

how do i do this? I am running ubuntu 14.04

Thanks