# Error reading webpage source code using Python

Tags: python, https

I'm new to Python and I've been trying to get the source code of a page and tried several methods on both Python 2 and 3 (here's one)

```
import urllib

url = "https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=u6d_VbzoMaei8wfE1oHgBw&gws_rd=ssl#q=test"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
source = f.read()
print source
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\openpage.py", line 4, in <module>
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1049, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 893, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 855, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1274, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

The last line suggest that the error comes from the secure search, but I can't seem to find a way around it.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146383/https-connection-python) post, but still no success.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://gist.github.com/3084b5ff8ce5b0fe7b84)

Comment: Do you have valid cacerts on your system and can you system do SSL in general? What does ``curl`` say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code you can try on Python3, using `urlparse`

```
import http.client
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = "https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=u6d_VbzoMaei8wfE1oHgBw&gws_rd=ssl#q=test"
p = urlparse(url)
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
conn.request('GET', p.path)
resp = conn.getresponse()
print('resp= {}'.format(resp.read()))
```

It will work based on your parameters to `conn.request()` function, though. You could try other method types like `HEAD` for example and your response will change accordingly.

If you want to test whether your request worked or not, you can always try:

```
print(resp.status)
```

In this case, it gives `200`. The list of status codes are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Some other [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples) can be found as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I seem to be getting much less information printed out as I do when I save the html file as a webpage and open it in notepad. Any idea why it isn't complete?

Comment: I figured my last comment could be a different problem and wanted to accept your answer, so I asked a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906705/html-source-code-of-https-pages-different-when-fetched-manually-vs-with-httpcon?noredirect=1#comment49851502_30906705).

Answer (score 2):

You are using https which is a secure protocol. It says

> SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Try http or use ssl 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

```
url = "http://www.google.ca
```