# How to make requests to a HTTPS page using urllib and proxies on python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, urllib, proxies

I am making something where I need to be sending requests with post data to a https page. While trying to make this I got the following error.

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Domain Not Found
```

So I made something else really quick just for testing.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


proxy = ["5.62.154.103:8085","141.101.132.43:8085"]
indeks = 0
for x in range(0,2):

print(proxy[indeks])
q = Request("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146383/https-connection-python")
q.set_proxy(proxy[indeks],"http")

a = urlopen(q).read()
print(a)
indeks += 1
print(indeks)
```

And I found out this gave me the same same error.
So I thought this was because the page was using https? Since I had no problems requesting http pages such as "http://httpbin.org/ip".

And https is not the problem here could someone explain me what I did wrong?

Thank you all in advance!