# Error reading web page in python but the url works on webrowser

Tags: python

I can access a web page from the browser but when accessing it programmaticaly, does not work

i have tried with quote_plus for the #k=#s

```
urlpage = 'https://www.dnp.gov.co/CONPES/documentos-conpes/Paginas/documentos-conpes.aspx#k=#s=11'
print(urlpage)

html = urlopen(urlpage)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146907

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: what error do you get? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Python uses different header `User-Agent` than browser and server may recognize it and block your request. Many servers don't like bots/scripts because scripts don't click on ads and server's owners don't get money. Getting data from server (using scripts) can be also treated as stealling.

Comment: Hi. I´m working on python 3.6. I´m using the urlopen because after that i use content = html.read() in order to use  scrap a table information that is on table within a CDATA section. My code after that is content = html.read()

    fileobject = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

    #print(soup)

    table = soup.find_all('table')[2] #Tabla de datos  I´m getting HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In Python3.x, use webbrowser module to open a weblink in webbrowser from program:

```
import webbrowser
urlpage = "https://www.dnp.gov.co/CONPES/documentos-conpes/Paginas/documentos-conpes.aspx#k=#s=11"
html = webbrowser.open(urlpage)
```