# How to ping an ip and get only the ms in the Tk with Python?

Tags: python, windows, ping

I want to make a little tk app that continuous ping an ip and only show the MS, like, "10ms"

how could I do?

Comment: Related: Ping a site in Python? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Windows `ping`, you'll have to parse the output from the command line.

This is very specific, but should work:

```
import os
while(1):
    ping = os.popen('ping www.google.com -n 1')
    result = ping.readlines()
    msLine = result[-1].strip()
    print msLine.splot(' = ')[-1]
```

Comment: No problem. I suggest you print the result of each line, so you can see exactly what it's doing. Also: please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To continuously ping an IP

```
os.system("ping -t 192.168.1.1")
```