# Checking mode availability using ping in RYU controller

Tags: python, ping, mininet, sdn, ryu

I’m trying to write code that checks if a node is up by pinging the node in ryu controller. If the node responds, then the node is marked as being up. I already have the code for the controller so I want to incorporate this ping code into the controller code.

So essentially I’m trying to find out how to ping a node using python program in ryu controller.

I’ve gone through various documentation but I can’t seem to find a direct way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535055/check-if-remote-host-is-up-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Create a packet and forward it through the port connected to the node.
By node I assume you mean a host and I assume you know:

- which port ((switches.Port object), or (dpid, port_no)) the host is connected to.
- the mac address of host.
- the ip address of host.

```py
port : switches.Port = port # (known)
dpid = port.dpid
port_no = port.port_no
```

```py
from ryu.lib.packet import packet, ether_types, ethernet, icmp
pkt = packet.Packet()
pkt.add_protocol(ethernet.ethernet(ethertype=ether_types.ETH_TYPE_IP, src=<src_mac>, dst=<dst_mac>))
pkt.add_protocol(icmp.icmp(...))
pkt.serialize()
send_packet_out(datapath, port_no, pkt.data)
```