# Ping from AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know I can fetch url from AppEngine. But I just want to ping a website, without to get any other data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"ping" as in ICMP or "ping" as in send an HTTP request without getting the full response?  If the latter, just send a HEAD request instead of a GET.

If the former, then that probably depends on your language of choice on AppEngine

- For python, check out
  [Ping a site in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)
- For java, check out http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-do-icmp-ping-in-java-jdk-15-and-above/

Comment: I don't want to get the full response. I just want to know that it's working. Some sites have very big index pages which is not good for my quota.

Comment: That's exactly what a HEAD request does, it retrieves the status header for a page but not the content.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [whitelist of modules](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/libraries.html) and an FAQ about [notable exclusions](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#libraries). You can't do it; use whaley's HEAD request.

It is also possible for an ICMP un-pingable to serve web-pages and a ICMP pingable site to do nothing but respond to pings.