# Python, Getting All LAN IPs

Tags: python, windows, networking, ip, lan

I am trying to print all the Live IPs that connected to my Network in the fastest way.
I tried to ping in a for loop, but it is very slow:

```
def PingTry(host):
    ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", host], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = ping.communicate()
    print out #This will show me the ping result, I can check the content and see if the host replyed or not
```

As I said, it is very slow (I need to do this 255 times).

I tried to connect to it using TCP connection with port 80:

```
import socket
IP = '192.168.1.100'
PORT = 80
tcpsoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsoc.listen(SOMAXCONN)
try:
    tcpsoc.bind(ADDR)
except Exception,ex:
    print "host is down!"
```

But still, it doesn't work for this IP, although it is working for the router IP

Is there a way to getting all the live IPs faster?

Comment: the reason ping is slow is because you are actually waiting for responses (pong) from the interface. you can instead just generate a list of connected interfaces with arp -a.

Comment: I tried using arp -a, but I only get the router's IP address in the interface list, although my phone and my laptop are connected to the network too

Comment: What operating system are you on? Can you be certain that you have superuser (or at least `CAP_NET_ADMIN`) privileges?

Comment: @phihag I'm on Windows 7 64 Bit and yes, I have Admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is the appropriate way to ask a machine if it has claimed an IP address. It is slow because (depending on your platform) the ping timeout is usually a second. You can speed it up by reducing the timeout or by using the [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module to send multiple pings at the same time.

You implement a ping in python directly: [Pinging servers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Alternatively, use a tool like [nmap](http://nmap.org/).

Comment: I don't want to use a program to get all the connected IPs, I want to do so in Python.

I already looked at this thread before I asked this question, although I setted the timeout to 1 sec, or 0.5 sec

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`ping`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx) in parallel with a [multiprocessing Pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def ping(host):
    ping = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-w', '500', host],
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = ping.communicate()
    return (out, error)
addresses = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2',] # etc.
pool = Pool(10) # Increase number to increase speed and resource consumption
ping_results = pool.map(ping)
print(ping_results)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Alternatively, use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ctypes.html) to call [`ICMPSendEcho`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the `ping` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use different approach, the Router usually is holding all the active IP addresses in its ARP table, assuming this is a professional network and any basic professional Router is answering SNMP requests, use Python and some SNMP package (like: PySNMP) and get the list from it.

Hint: ARP Table OID = 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22 (ipNetToMediaTable)

After getting that list, I would double check it using ICMP(ping) or any other responsive protocol.

Answer (score 0):

[scapy provides a function](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#arp-ping). I am not sure whether this is multithreaded. If not, just call the function for different ranges in a multithreaded way.

```
>>> arping("192.168.1.*")
```