# ICMP Message in python

Tags: python, icmp

I'm trying to write a program that sees who is on my subnet, for that I want to send ICMP message to all ip possible in my subnet.

My question is how to send ICMP message in python?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK massage isn't usually transmitted via ICMP

Comment: related: [Pinging servers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the great module [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html). With it, sending ICMP-packets is as easy as this:

```
>>> send(IP(dst="1.2.3.4")/ICMP())
```

Have fun! :-)

Scapy can be installed via pip or downloaded at PyPI. Maybe some hosts don't reply to ICMP ping requests, you could also try ARP in a local network.

Comment: Yes, try it out & if it satisfies your needs please mark this thread as solved. CU