# How to detect what output is and do if statement from it?

Tags: python, if-statement, cmd, os.system

Basically I am writing a script in Python that will check for me the status of my servers. I need it to ping five different IPs and then detect what the output is. I will then need an if statement for example:

```
import.os
Server1 = os.system('ping 123.123.123.123')
if Server1 == 'Request timed out':
     print('Server 1 is down.')
else:
     print('Server 1 is up.')
```

I am not exactly sure how to go about this. Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pinging servers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted big X/Y here. You want do do X. You don't know how to do X. You think Y is the best way to do X and are asking about Y. If you want to know about X, see [Ivc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python).

I'm going to answer Y but letting you know that Y is not the best way to do it.

```
import subprocess
import locale

encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "123.123.123.123"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()[0]
if 'Request timed out' in out.decode(encoding):
    print 'the host is down'
else: 
    print 'the host is up'
```

Then you would need to decide exactly what to do when the host is down and when the host is up.

Comment: This is working well. How would I go about parsing it though?

Comment: @user2934716 it depends on the output. Please update the question the output ping gives you when successful and when unsuccessful.

Comment: This output would mean the server is up:
b'\r\nPinging 123.123.123.123 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 123.123.123.123: bytes=32 time=230ms TTL=44\r\nReply from 123.123.123.123: bytes=32 time=230ms TTL=44\r\nReply from 123.123.123.123: bytes=32 time=233ms TTL=44\r\nReply from 123.123.132.123: bytes=32 time=233ms TTL=44\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 123.123.123.123:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 230ms, Maximum = 233ms, Average = 231ms\r\n'

(Second part in next comment)

Comment: This would mean the server is down.<br><br>b'\r\nPinging 123.123.123.123 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 123.123.123.123:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),\r\n'<br><br>Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not unusual for `ping` to get some timeouts on a working connection. Maybe better to check for `Reply from` (so it would consider "host down" only, if all packets got lost)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but, "TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API"

Comment: You probably need to decode the output first because you're reading binary data not a string. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This is working perfectly. You sir deserve a medal.