# Scan range of IP with ping command and give specific result

Tags: python, windows, cmd, ip, ping

hello i want to create a ping script on python where it will ping 3 ips and give me out only the result if the server is alive i want to give me the packet loss and generate if the ms time is less than 100 . I have no pythong expert skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change the hostname with List and provide the ip address in the code given in the another StackOverflow thread

[Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468640/python-function-to-test-ping)

Sample Code

```
import subprocess
hosts = ['link1','link2','link3']
for host in hosts:
    result = subprocess.check_output("ping google.com")
    print result
    # do some process on result
```

Comment: what about the time and the packet loss? will be listed after executing that code? because i want it to give the pack met losss result and the ms time

Comment: is there any way to print the result value in a text file?

Comment: see you have to do processing on result and extract whatever information you are looking for.You can use Regex https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html . If you want to do continuous monitoring then better way you use Threads.