# python script deleting text immediately after writing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on script that checks on ping from several groups of devices and writing the devices ip to text file when the ping is successful

```
import os

ip_list=[]
data = open("data.txt",'w')

def pngtest():
    g=4
    s=2
    e=106
    while g < 11:
        for ip in range(s,e):
            ip_list.append('10.0.'+str(g)+'.'+str(ip))
        if g == 8:
            s=5
            e=122
        elif g == 9:
            s=2
            e=198
        elif g == 10:
            s=2
            e=254
        else:
            s=2
            e=106
        g +=1
pngtest()

for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
    if "Received = 4" in response and 'TTL' in response:
        data.write(f"{ip}")
    else:
        print(f"ping {ip} failed")
data.close()
```

the problem is that it seems that the script does not writing any data to the text file.
how do I fix this?

Comment: This if statement is never true in  your code, probably: `if "Received = 4" in response and 'TTL' in response:`

Comment: Are you sure the data is written, then deleted or could it be never written at all

Comment: try using 'a' mode instead of 'w' in the `open` function
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `ping -c 1` will stop sending packets after single request.

```
for ip in ip_list:
  print("Checking" + IP)
  response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip + "> /dev/null" )
  if response == 0:
    data.write(f"{ip}")
  else:
    print(f"ping {ip} failed")
```

Maybe you should reframe your question. It is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468640/python-function-to-test-ping/39563638).

Answer (score 0):

try adding a timeout to `ping`

```
response = os.popen(f"ping -t 4 {ip}").read()
```

also print the `response` to see why  you `if` didn't work.

```
print(f"ping {ip} failed response={response}")
```