# How To Ping IP With Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn networking with python and would like to make a simple ping script that includes the response time as well. I don't really know where to start and if I could use the the socket module to help with this project.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python

Comment: ICMP is a Layer 3 protocol in OSI model, I dont think think you need sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the `os` module from the standard python library:

```
import os

hosts = [] # list of host addresses

for host in hosts:
    os.system('ping ' + host)
```

Comment: can it also  output the response time, sorry I forgot that out of the question when i posted.