# Create Python script to ping many hostnames

Tags: python, shell, ip, ping, hostname

I have a CSV file with the hostnames of 6,000+ servers. I need to ping each one.

Any idea how to create a python script like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried that? Where is your code?

Comment: Going to be the same in any language. Read the file into a structure of some kind. Run a loop over the structure, reading one with each loop. In the loop, make a call to each server. Questions will be around whether you want to do it one a time, or send them all off in batches. But it's pretty simple stuff.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

while read hostname
do
ping -c 1 -t 1 "$hostname" > /dev/null 2>&1 && 
echo "Ping Status of $hostname : Success" || 
echo "Ping Status of $hostname : Failed" 
done < app.txt

Answer (score 0):

Open file, for-loop through hosts (easiest if 1 per line), then ping.

To learn how to ping, try reading this article:
[Pinging servers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Then, just make a small routine that opens file, loops through lines, and pings each one.

```
with open("file") as f: 
  for host in f:
    ping(host)  # <- not legit; replace this line; see comment below
```

Note: you will need to replace "ping(host)" with code that you create after being inspired by the "Pinging servers in Python" Q&A or another article... or by just flat-out copying their example.