# No module named 'core' when using pyping for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to import `pyping` for Python 3 but I am getting below error:

```
virt01@virt01:~/Python_Admin$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyping/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from core import *
ImportError: No module named 'core'
>>>
```

*Update 1*

```
virt01@virt01:~/Python_Admin$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyping/
core.py  __init__.py  __pycache__
```

Comment: Is this build date ,default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) ?

Comment: @bernie and any solution around ? I have tried google but couldnt found

Comment: can you do the ll or ls command to verify that core.py is in the folder /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyping/

Comment: @goCards I have updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because of absolute imports being in effect (more precisely, the lack of implicit relative imports) for Python 3 and the fact that the `pyping` module was most likely only written for Python 2. Whereas in Python 2 you can do:

```
from core import *
```

In Python 3 (or if you have `from __future__ import absolute_import` in Python 2), you have to do:

```
from .core import *
```

or

```
from pyping.core import *
```

You have two options:

1. ask the module author to make it compatible with Python 3
2. fork it yourself and make it compatible with Python 3 (you can look into using `2to3` for this)

Comment: Thank you , I will 2nd option. But to make 2to3 do I need to take permission/approval from Module Author ?

Comment: @Raja The project's [license](https://github.com/certator/pyping/blob/master/LICENSE) is GPLv2, which means you can modify it as you like, provided that, if you sell it or distribute it, you need to provide the (now-modified) source under the same license. See the [GPL FAQs](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html).

Comment: 2to3 not working directly and given 2 solutions for python 3 too. any other ideas

Comment: @Raja There's no other way. `2to3` is not a completely automated solution. You have to debug and port the code to Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ping3](https://github.com/kyan001/ping3) library. But it [requires](https://github.com/kyan001/ping3/issues/10) root permission on your machine. [This link](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/01/17/unprivileged-icmp-sockets-on-linux/) shows the workaround (unprivileged ICMP sockets which allow to use ping without root).