# Pinging without calling system commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping

I need a way to **ping** remote machines **without calling system commands**. And **if possible, without admin or root access**. Something that could work **on any platform**.

I had a quick look into `python3 -m pip install pyping` but importing it returns me the following :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'`.

Also it require root/admin access which I would like to avoid.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: If by `ping` you mean ICMP-based pings, there's a reason `ping` itself is setuid. There are alternatives based on different protocols, but if you want to send a "real" ping, you (on most platforms) need root.

Comment: On most platforms you need admin privileges to send ICMP packets. That's why the `ping` binary is setuid root on Unix systems.

Comment: What's the real goal you're trying to accomplish? If you just want to check network connectivity, the easy answer is to do it with a different tool / at a different layer.

Comment: ICMP on Unix or Window platforms require root or administrator privilege, because this protocol can be abused to launch DDOS attacks or to malicious scan hosts.  What is your objective for 'pinging' another host without the required privileges?

Comment: The documentation for the module pyping states that admin privilege are required on Window platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ICMP Ping is a "special" kind of networking that uses a raw socket. I don't super understand it myself, but TLDR is that it seems difficult to do without privilege escalation.

If you know for a fact a given TCP port on the target machine(s) are going to be open, you can just try to establish a TCP connection to that port. For example, if you can SSH into these machines, the standard SSH port (22) is usually open. You don't need to actually communicate - just establish a TCP connection to that port then drop it. See [TcpCommunication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication)

Answer (score -2):

this is because the module was introduced for python 2,however if you want to use it with python3 you can manipulate it or use `2to3` module,this question was asked in [unable to import pyping for python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330964/unable-to-import-pyping-for-python3)