# Create a python function to run speedtest-cli/ping in terminal and output result to a log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

I am learning python and I'm trying to run some terminal command lines using python; eg: speed test and ping. I am using functional programming as my method of programming. However, upon reading more and browsing more with functional programming based from docs.python.org[1](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html). I don't think that I am doing it the right way. 
My question is:
 Is it good for a function to not have an argument/parameters and just input the command/s directly inside it? 
And is it really a good option to use os.system or is there a better module to use?

Here is the sample of my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# tasks.py

import os

def task_speedtest():
    os.system("speedtest-cli >> /Desktop/logs")

def task_ping():
    os.system("ping www.google.com -c5 >> /Desktop/logs")

task_speedtest()
task_ping()
```

Comment: you can import speedtest, as it is actually a python module, and call the functions natively. Please see documentation of speedtest-cli

Comment: You should not use `os.system`, rather, use the newer, more powerful [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, there is nothing wrong with directly executing the commands in the function without using arguments/parameters in your function.

You could always add a parameter in your function definition to specify the path for example so that you can call the function and execute the command using different directories:

```
def task_speedtest(path):
    os.system("speedtest-cli >> " + path)

def task_ping():
    os.system("ping www.google.com -c5 >> " + path)

path = "/Desktop/logs"
task_speedtest(path)
task_ping(path)
```

---

Regarding your second question, **yes, there is a better module to use than `os.system`**.

There exists an upgraded version of `os.system` which is [`Subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html), according to the official Python documentation *(Python 3.6)*:

> The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to
>   their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This
>   module intends to replace several older modules and functions.
>
> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle.
>
> ```
> subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None)
> ```
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance

There is even a section on how to replace `os.system` with the new subprocess [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system):

```
sts = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")
# becomes
sts = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)
```

I suggest you read more about the new module in the official Python documentation of Subprocess here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you. I got a better view of functions now. I will try to use subprocess now instead of os.system. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the speedtest-cli API as detailed in the [wiki](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/wiki)

(following code from the wiki)

```
import speedtest

servers = []
# If you want to test against a specific server
# servers = [1234]

s = speedtest.Speedtest()
s.get_servers(servers)
s.get_best_server()
s.download()
s.upload()
s.results.share()

results_dict = s.results.dict()
```

for pinging in python, see [this question and many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a good one since this can return the result as dict which maybe good for getting data.