# server ping - Where and how to fix the TypeError "argument of type 'classname' is not iterable"?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pyqt5, ping

While testing a server ping script posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55656177/8928024) at SO I ran into an error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'MyCOM' is not iterable

To see what is parsed to `subprocess.list2cmdline(seq)`: seq was checked:

> parse result: ['ping', '-n', '192.168.0.2', '-w', '1000', <**main**.MyCOM object at 0x000002D26267F678>]

MyCOM is a classname. What, how and where should this be fixed to work? Full traceback: see below.

My GUI script:

```py
    class MainGUI(etc...):
        def __init__(self, *args, parent=None):

            ...snippet...

            self.mycom_thread = MyCOM()
            self.mycom_thread.start()

            ...snippet...

    class MyCOM(QThread):

        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            QThread.__init__(self, parent)

            self.ping_okay = 0

        def ping(host_or_ip, packets=1, timeout=1000):
            ''' Calls system "ping" command, returns True if ping succeeds.
            Required parameter: host_or_ip (str, address of host to ping)
            Optional parameters: packets (int, number of retries), timeout (int, ms to wait for response)
            Does not show any output, either as popup window or in command line.
            Python 3.5+, Windows and Linux compatible (Mac not tested, should work)

            Credits to: SO user Jose Francisco Lopez Pimentel.
            '''
            # The ping command is the same for Windows and Linux, except for the "number of packets" flag.
            if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
                print ('some text')
                command = ['ping', '-n', str(packets), '-w', str(timeout), host_or_ip]
                # run parameters: capture output, discard error messages, do not show window
                result = subprocess.run(command, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, creationflags=0x08000000)
                # 0x0800000 is a windows-only Popen flag to specify that a new process will not create a window.
                # On Python 3.7+, you can use a subprocess constant:
                #   result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
                # On windows 7+, ping returns 0 (ok) when host is not reachable; to be sure host is responding,
                # we search the text "TTL=" on the command output. If it's there, the ping really had a response.
                return result.returncode == 0 and b'TTL=' in result.stdout
            else:
                command = ['ping', '-c', str(packets), '-w', str(timeout), host_or_ip]
                # run parameters: discard output and error messages
                result = subprocess.run(command, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
                return result.returncode == 0

        def run(self):

            check = 1
            IP = "192.168.0.2"

            while check == 1:
                print (self.ping(IP))
```

The full traceback:

> ```py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "mymain.py", line 1156, in run
>         print (self.ping(IP))
>       File "mymain.py", line 1137, in ping
>         result = subprocess.run(command, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, creationflags=0x08000000)
>       File "x\lib\subprocess.py", line 383, in run
>         with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>       File "x\lib\subprocess.py", line 678, in __init__
>         restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       File "x\lib\subprocess.py", line 933, in _execute_child
>         args = list2cmdline(args)
>       File "x\lib\subprocess.py", line 443, in list2cmdline
>         needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
>     TypeError: argument of type 'MyCOM' is not iterable
>     Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from 'x\\lib\\threading.py'>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "x\lib\threading.py", line 1294, in _shutdown
>         _main_thread._delete()
>       File "x\lib\threading.py", line 1013, in _delete
>         del _active[get_ident()]
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this (apparently inheritance) type of error the following line should be replaced:

```
def ping(host_or_ip, packets=1, timeout=1000):
```

by

```
def ping(self, host_or_ip, packets=1, timeout=1000):
```

providing `self` as first argument otherwise the inheritance goes incorrect and the error mentioned is thrown back to you.