# Ping a CSV file of IP Adresses in Python

Tags: python-3.x, networking, network-programming, ip, ping

Beginner with a beginner question: I am trying to build a python program to ping a csv file of ip addresses.

This script is nearly there, however when I convert the csv data to a list and use the for loop
on it... the brackets and quotes remain in the ip address ['10.10.10.1'] which prevents me from pinging.

I know there are numerous ways to remove quotes/brackets from list items, but what would work best here?

I think I am nearly there, what is a simple solution to this?

```
import os
import csv

csvFile = open('hosts.csv')
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
csvData = list(csvReader)

for ip in csvData:
    response = os.system('ping ' + str(ip))
    if response == 0:
        print(ip, 'is up')
    else:
        print(ip, 'is down')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually embedding a list into a list with the `csvData = list(csvReader)` line.

`csv.reader()` returns a list of strings for each row read from the csv file.  So if you have multiple lines in your file you'll end up with n-rows of lists.

The first `for` loop will handle if your file has multiple rows.  The second `for` loop will parse through the list returned by `csv.reader()`.

Also, your ping statement will continue to ping.  There are other unexpected issues you may hit but that's for another question.

Try this:

```
import os
import csv

with open('hosts.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for line in reader:
    for ip in line:
      response = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + str(ip))
      if response == 0:
        print (ip, ' is up')
      else:
        print (ip, ' is down')
```

**References**

[Python3 CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
[Pinging Servers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for the response Ken, really appreciate it!