# I need to know how to get python to constently check if it's connected to internet

Tags: python

I need Python to check if it's connected to the internet every time a loop runs. I need the output to be in a variable, a yes or no thing.

This is the code I tried but it never repeats in a loop.

```
try:
    socket.create_connection(("www.swisscows.com",80))
    b= [1]
    pass
except OSError:
    b= [0]
    pass
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Define "Connected to the internet"

Comment: Well, you need a loop; `try` isn't one. Also, what's the purpose of `b`? (Both `pass` statements are unnecessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to execute a ping request against a web site that you know should be online at all time. See the response here: [Pinging servers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Comment: the ping works but the program won't repeat

Comment: You updated your code with the ping method as given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python and it still does not work? In that case the problem seems to be somewhere else in your code. Can you post the complete loop that is not working?