# IP Address Monitoring Script

Tags: python

I am trying to code a script, that contantly pings a couple ip addres, and print out the result...

I dont know how to modify it, to print out the text only if the state change... So i'd like to ping the destinations continously but, i'd like to see the result only if it changes...

ex. if 192.168.1.10 responds in my logs i'd like to see " ip, came up" and thats all...

i have multiple loops, but unfortunatly i cant find how to do it...

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import os

def identifier():
  IP_ADDRESS = ["192.168.1.10","192.168.1.11","192.168.1.20","192.168.1.188","192.168.1.80","192.168.1.1"]
  while True:
    for ip in IP_ADDRESS:
      ping = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-n','1','-w','15', ip],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      status_change = False
      status = 0
      ping.wait()
      if ping.poll():
        status_change = True
        status = 1
      else: 
        status_change = True
        status= 0
      if status_change:
        if status ==1:
          print(ip," went down")
        else:
          print(ip, " came up")
 


identifier()
```

Comment: You could maintain a 2nd list of the same size as your IP list and store the most recent status for each ping there. Or you could store them in a dict, keyed off ip address.

Comment: i was thinking too about the idea with the 2nd list... but.. i was curious if there is any other method.

Comment: I just gave you a second option (the dict). Both are simple to implement.

Comment: A dict is much more efficient than a list in this context. Using the right data structure for the job matters.

Comment: the dict was the perfect solution.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```py
import os
import platform  # For getting the operating system name
import subprocess  # For executing a shell command
import time  # Do not spam the IPs

INTERVAL = 5  # seconds


def ping(host):
    """
    Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
    Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if the host name is valid.
    """

    # Option for the number of packets as a function of
    param = "-n" if platform.system().lower() == "windows" else "-c"

    # Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
    command = ["ping", param, "1", host]

    # Redirecting output to /dev/null on Unix-based systems or NUL on Windows
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        return subprocess.call(command, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull) == 0


def identifier():
    IP_ADDRESS = [
        "192.168.1.10",
        "192.168.1.11",
        "192.168.1.20",
        "192.168.1.188",
        "192.168.1.80",
        "192.168.1.1",
    ]

    first_status = True
    status = {} # Keep track of the status of the IPs
    while True:
        for ip in IP_ADDRESS:
            if first_status:
                # Get the first status of the IPs
                status[ip] = ping(ip)
                continue
            if status[ip] != ping(ip): # If the status of the IP changed
                status[ip] = not status[ip]
                print(f"IP {ip} changed status to {'UP' if status[ip] else 'DOWN'}")

        first_status = False
        # Avoid spamming the IPs
        time.sleep(INTERVAL)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    identifier()
```

If the performance is critical, you could separate the IPs into threads to send all the pings without waiting to receive the answer from others.

Source : [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684938/15860367) for the ping function, modified by me to make it silent.