# Is it possible to check if a computer is connected to a domain with python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to check if a computer is connected to a domain?
I want to be sure that the computer is connected to my company´s network with python (means that he is inside the company, using company´s network), so It would allow some scripts to run.

Comment: What do you mean? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python) what you are looking for?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check that a computer connected to a certain network running `ping` command based on [ICMP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol).

In Python, you can achieve it with [pythonping library](https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/).

But the computer executing this script should have access to the specified network.

Comment: You can also just call the `ping` command using `os.system("ping ...")`. No external library required.