# Python sort links by latency

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of links for eg:
`['google.com','facebook.com','instagram.com']`

I wanna sort the links by their latency. Is there any way i can ping the website and check latency?

If it's a video playing link then is it possible to test the speed?

Edit: Nick's answer solves the latency for me but still looking for an answer for speed of the server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pinging servers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python)

Comment: You can check the ping times by running `ping` and parsing the output.  That doesn't say much about latency.  In other words, you're not going to learn very much.  There are a LOT of variables in ping time.  You can learn your total network load, but to get individual web sites, you need a packet filter.  That's advanced.

Comment: this question needs more focus, it's too broad

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to fetch the link using requests, then measure the time elapsed. E.g:

```
for link in links:
    duration = requests.get(link).elapsed.total_seconds()
    print(link, duration)
```

[Documentation.](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=elapsed#requests.Response.elapsed)

Note: this won't measure the loading time of the entire page. For example, if the site plays a video, then the actual video won't be included in the page, only an HTML element which tells the browser where to find it.

Comment: This works for me. But is there any way to test the speed of the website (at what speed will the video load)?

Comment: @sahil Yes, but it's much more complicated. You'd need to run a browser using something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). Then, you'd need to detect when the video is loaded. Doing that for a single site would be pretty easy. Doing it in a fully general way would be pretty hard.