# Pinging network devices in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ping

In Python, is there a way to ping a network device like switch, router etc. without logging to particular site server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Worked on top of a solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32684938/2525388)  . If you want to just 'ping', just use the function ping({ insert IP})

```
import platform    # For getting the operating system name
import subprocess  # For executing a shell command

def ping(host):
    """
    Returns True if host (str) responds to a ping request.
    Remember that a host may not respond to a ping (ICMP) request even if the host name is valid.
    """

    # Option for the number of packets as a function of
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

    # Building the command. Ex: "ping -c 1 google.com"
    command = ['ping', param, '1', '-t','1', host]

    return subprocess.call(command) == 0

#Simple test to see how many IPs are allocated by my router
IPV4_in_router=[f"192.168.86.{x}" for x in range(1,254)]
used=[]
for x in IPV4_in_router:
    y=ping(x)
    if y:
        used.append(x)
print(used)
```

Comment: You may want to consider crediting https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684938/2525388 since the ping() function appears to come from there.

Comment: @Red, Thanks for the response.. i am aware of ping function but it wont work for the private IP.. what if we need to ping the any private ip from our local system ?

Comment: @Jung-suk Private IP works. Anything inside your Subnet should be able to be able to connect. Make sure you arent connected to a VPN, else you're on a different IP than your physical router.