# How to block response from GET request

Tags: http, python-requests, proxy, http-proxy, get-request

I'm using python requests library. I **have** to send GET request to a website. The response body weights a lot and I'm using a proxy and pay per-gb. I need to block response being received by a proxy server to save bandwidth. I cannot use head requests since they are restricted by the website.

Everything I was able to find is discarding the response body from memory but that has nothing with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to receive anything why are you sending a GET request? Are you actually trying to receive some different information?

For example if you were simply trying to test that the site is up you could use ping as per[how to ping in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402323/9650095)

```
import os
hostname = "google.com" #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
#and then check the response...
if response == 0:
    print(f"{hostname} is up!")
else:
    print(f"{hostname} is down!")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I need to send the get request so the website knows I requested the data and it writes it in the database. It sends the heavy response that I don't need. They discard all requests than GET.