# How to determine the IP address of the server after connecting with urllib2?

Tags: python, ip-address, urllib2

I am downloading data from a server using urllib2. But I need to determine the IP address of the server to which I am connected.

```
import urllib2
STD_HEADERS = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
                    */*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64;en-US;rv:1.9.2.12)     
                           Gecko/20101028 Firefox/3.6.12'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, STD_HEADERS)
data =  urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Please don't ask me to find the IP address using the URL as this does not guarantee that the server from which the data is downloaded and the IP address query resolve to the same IP address in case of 'HTTPRedirects' or a loadbalancing server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib2, socket, urlparse

# set up your request as before, then:
data = urllib2.urlopen(request)
addr = socket.gethostbyname(urlparse.urlparse(data.geturl()).hostname)
```

`data.geturl()` returns the URL that was used to actually retrieve the resource, after any redirects. The hostname is then fished out with `urlparse` and handed off to `socket.gethostbyname` to get the IP address.

Some hosts may have more than one IP address for a given hostname, so it's still possible that the request was fulfilled by a different server, but this is as close as you're gonna get. A `gethostbyname` right after the URL request is going to use your DNS cache anyway and unless you're dealing with a time-to-live of, like, 1 second, you're going to be getting the same server you just used.

If this is insufficient, you *could* spin off a thread and do a `lsof` while still connected to the remote server. I'm sure you could convince `urllib2` to leave the connection open for a while so this would succeed. This seems like rather more work than it's worth, though.

Comment: The `netloc` part may contain port number, if this is specified, so `socket.gethostbyname(urlparse.urlparse('http://www.google.com:80').netloc)` will fail with message `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`.

Comment: Changed to `hostname`

Answer (score 7):

Here's what works for me on Python 2.7:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from socket import fromfd
>>> from socket import AF_INET
>>> from socket import SOCK_STREAM
>>> r = urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/')
>>> mysockno = r.fileno()
>>> mysock = fromfd( mysockno, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
>>> (ip, port) = mysock.getpeername()
>>> print "got IP %s port %d" % (ip, port)
got IP 198.252.206.140 port 80
```

Comment: also somewhat obvious, if the request fails to connect, you'll never get past the `urlopen` and won't know what ip was being tried.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question but I've find that the response object returned by urllib2 contains the ip. This looks a bit like a hack but it works.

```
import urllib2
STD_HEADERS = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
                    */*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64;en-US;rv:1.9.2.12)     
                           Gecko/20101028 Firefox/3.6.12'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, STD_HEADERS)
data =  urllib2.urlopen(request)

data.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. It's the *exact* functionality the asker was looking for. And so was I. +1

Answer (score 1):

Kudos should go [to gawry for his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512413/476371). However, I didn't want to mutilate his answer with my additions, which seem to be somewhat longer than his full answer. So please see this answer as an addition to his answer.

### Caveat emptor

**This will only work on Python 2.x with `urllib2`.** The structure of the classes have changed in Python 3.x, so even the casual compatibility trick:

try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

won't save you. I guess that's the reason why you shouldn't rely on internals of classes, especially when the attributes start with an underscore and are therefore by convention not part of the public interface, albeit being accessible.

**Conclusion:** the following trick below doesn't work on Python 3.x.

### Extracting IP:port from an `HTTPResponse`

Here's a condensed version of his answer:

```
import urllib2
r =  urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
peer = r.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()
print("%s connected\n\tIP and port: %s:%d\n\tpeer = %r" % (r.geturl(), peer[0], peer[1], peer))
```

Output will be something like this (trimmed `ei` parameter for privacy reasons):

```
http://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=_... connected
        IP and port: 173.194.120.95:80
        peer = ('173.194.120.95', 80)
```

Assuming `r` above is an `httplib.HTTPResponse` instance we make the following additional assumptions:

- its attribute `fp` (`r.fp`) is an instance of `class sock._fileobject`, created via `sock.makefile()` in the ctor of `httplib.HTTPResponse`
- attribute `_sock` (`r.fp._sock`) is the "socket" instance *passed to* the `class socket._fileobject` ctor, it will be of type
- attribute `fp` (`r.fp._sock.fp`) is another `socket._filetype` which wraps the real socket
- attribute `_sock` (`r.fp._sock.fp._sock`) is the real [socket object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket-objects)

Roughly `r.fp` is a `socket._fileobject`, while `r.fp._sock.fp._sock` is the actual socket instance (type `_socket.socket`) wrapped by a `socket._fileobject` wrapping another `socket._fileobject` (two levels deep). This is why we have this somewhat unusual `.fp._sock.fp._sock.` in the middle.

The variable returned by [`getpeername()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername) above is a tuple for IPv4. Element 0 is the IP in string form and element 1 is the port to which the connection was made on that IP. **Note: The documentation states that this format depends on the actual socket type.**

#### Extracting this information from `HTTPError`

On another note, since `urllib2.HTTPError` derives from `URLError` as well as `addinfourl` and stores the `fp` in an attribute of the same name, we can even extract that information from an `HTTPError` exception (not from `URLError`, though) by adding another `fp` to the mix like this:

```
import urllib2
try:
    r =  urllib2.urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/doesnotexist/url")
    peer = r.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()
    print("%s connected\n\tIP and port: %s:%d\n\tpeer = %r" % (r.geturl(), peer[0], peer[1], peer))
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    if e.fp is not None:
        peer = e.fp.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()
        print("%s: %s\n\tIP and port: %s:%d\n\tpeer = %r" % (str(e), e.geturl(), peer[0], peer[1], peer))
    else:
        print("%s: %s\n\tIP and port: <could not be retrieved>" % (str(e), e.geturl()))
```

Output will be something like this (unless someone at StackOverflow adds that URL ;)):

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found: https://stackoverflow.com/doesnotexist/url
        IP and port: 198.252.206.16:80
        peer = ('198.252.206.16', 80)
```