# check if connected to wifi AccessPoint in python

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am using a raspberry pi to transmit udp packets over wifi to a local udp server.I need to transmit the data only if the RasPi is connected to the access point( internet connectivity is not required). [Checking network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764291/checking-network-connection) describes how to check internet connectivity, which will consume more time than checking local connectivity. Is there any way in python to check whether the device is connected to access point?

Comment: you could use the solution in the thread you mentioned yourself to check the ip address of your access point ... although to me some kind of ping would be better but maybe that's not available in python ...