# Best way to check if Python program is connected to the Internet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using `python-requests` and noticed that it returns unrelated errors after failing to fetch a web page when not connected to the Internet.

The [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) mentions Exceptions, but not how to use them. How should the program verify that it is indeed connected, and fail nicely if not?

I currently have no error-handling system in place, and this is what I get:

```
File "mem.py", line 78, in <module>
    login()
  File "mem.py", line 38, in login
    csrf = s.cookies['csrftoken']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 276, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 331, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

Comment: What are the specific errors you're seeing, and what is your error/exception handling code currently doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764291/checking-network-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that HTTP errors are not raised by default in `python-requests`. This answer sums it up nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460981/908703

```
import requests

def connected_to_internet(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=5):
    try:
        _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("No internet connection available.")
    return False
```