# Django: How to restrict django to load views without internet connection?

Tags: python, django

I have some views that require internet to work.I want to restrict access to all my views if there is no internet connection when i run locally. How can i do this ?

Comment: Um. How will your website work at all if there is no internet?

Comment: Are you maybe asking how to do something client side if there's no internet? Or is this some kind of proxy system? A bit more detail would help the question make sense.

Comment: Im running it locally. So it runs anyway

Comment: @DhanyaM OK. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764291/checking-network-connection

Comment: I don't practically need a function. I wannt it to be done when i start my local server

Answer (score 0):

You can try some django package to work with html5 offline capabilities: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/offline/

HTML5 allows some offline features, never used it thought: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

But it's what allows some Google Apps to work offline.