# How to check if user is connected to internet in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib3

I am python 3.5 and using urllib3 and I have seen various examples but they were of urllib2 that's why I asked this question ,I have a bit of code which need internet but if user is not connected I want to show them a warning that device is not connected to internet so how can I do this.

Comment: Can you please post what code you've tried so far?

Comment: You make a request and handle the exception once it is raised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764291/checking-network-connection)

Comment: No as I don't know about urllib2 and I am using urllib3

Comment: It works with any version of `urllib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this where you check for connection to a site.

```
import urllib.request 
import urllib.parse 

try: 
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')        
except Exception as e: 
    print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive not used urllib before but you can try something like:

```
try:
    #you put your code here
    #and it will raise an exception if
    #network connection is not available
    #so you catch that
except:
    #your warning code
```