# Check internet connection Python

Tags: python

I was wondering how I would check if a users internet connection is on/off in python, if its off I want the program to close. I would prefer to do this by pinging and then looping over 25 minutes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764291/how-can-i-see-if-theres-an-available-and-active-network-connection-in-python

Answer (score -1):

Try to reach a website with request, if ConnectionError raise means there is no internet connection

[Source](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-python)

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/"
timeout = 5
try:
    request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
    print("Connected to the Internet")
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
    print("No internet connection.")
```