# How to check if a node is up/online?

Tags: python

I want my script to [ssh] remote login to a different machine to do something but before that I want to check: that node is not the localhost and the node is online, otherwise exit. What's the best [easiest??] way of doing that? Thanks for your advise in advance. Cheers!!

---

**Update-1 @Jakob: Error message**

Am I doing something wrong? Running the script, I get this:

```
File "./pingTest.py", line 9, in ?
    ping('10.0.11.20')
  File "./pingTest.py", line 5, in ping
    process = subprocess.Popen('ping %s' % target, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The very same thing happens on v2.6 as well. Cheers!!

---

**Update-2 @Jakob: Still not working**

So, this is the script now, with some minor modification:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, subprocess
def ping(target):
    process = subprocess.Popen('ping -c 1 -A %s' % target, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    results = process.communicate()[0]
    print(results)
    #return "Reply from %s" % target in results
    print "Reply from %s" % target in results

ping(sys.argv[1])
```

I changed the `ping` statement a little bit, so that it sends ECHO_REQUEST packet just once. Also changed the `return` to `print` to get some information on the screen. And, this is what I get when I run the script.

```
$ ./pingTest.py 10.0.11.1
PING 10.0.11.1 (10.0.11.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.11.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.665 ms

--- 10.0.11.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.665/0.665/0.665/0.000 ms

False

$ ./pingTest.py 10.0.11.2
PING 10.0.11.2 (10.0.11.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.11.20 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.0.11.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms


False
```

10.0.11.1 is an up and running host (as you can see from the first print statement) but it's saying `False` - am I actually doing it right?

If I actually print the `results` this way:

```
for tx in results:
    print "Result: ", tx
```

I get the `Result` like this:

```
Result:  P
Result:  I
Result:  N
Result:  G
Result:   
Result:  1
Result:  0
......
......
```

So, it's actually doing rather something else (??). Or maybe, I didn't able to follow your script at all. Any comment or suggestion? Cheers!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ping a site in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

Comment: I'd recommend against ping.  I know quite some hosts blocking ICMP packets, but allowing SSH connections.  Just try to connect -- it will fail if the host is down.

Comment: @S.Lott: already looked in the post you mention - too many suggestions to get easily confused. And another thing, as Sven said, ping could be blocked as well. Cheers!!

Comment: @Sven: What I actually want is not to execute ssh command at all in the first place if there is no response. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: "too many suggestions"?  What can that mean?  Please **update** this question to list the choices and explain what's wrong with each one.  Otherwise, we have no idea why you don't simply choose one.

Answer (score 0):

As sven says. I think there is a method to set a new timeout on socket. So just connect and if it times out consider it offline.

EDIT:

```
Code examples
import subprocess
def ping(target):
    process = subprocess.Popen('ping %s' % target, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    results = process.communicate()[0]
    return "Reply from %s" % target in results
```

Comment: You can change how the ping program is called by changing the Popen line, it takes quite a time for unreachable targets because it is literately waiting for the ping program to time out. Here is me using it, `In [4]: ping('192.168.0.1')
Out[4]: False

In [5]: ping('74.125.230.144')
Out[5]: True`

Comment: @Jakob: I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` for subprocess.py while run the script. I've updated my original post with the details. Cheers!!

Comment: @Jakob: Didn't quite follow you - where should I set that?

Comment: `process = subprocess.Popen('ping %s' % target, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)`

Comment: @Jakob: Sorry for not updating. I'm still not sure if it's actually working - "False" is always being returned regardless of node status. Updated my original post with details. cheers!!