# Twisted and ICMP (txNetTools)

Tags: python, twisted, ping, icmp

Several times I've seen mention that for asynchronous ping is good to use twisted.

I written implementation on threads (like [Ping a site in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python))

But on ~200 threads i have crush

On page http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/ProjectsUsingTwisted i find
txNetTools - Ping, traceroute, icmp, etc., implemented in Twisted, and a library for those who want to build their own network tools.

Has anyone used this library?

I tried to use it ping.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Pinger(ICMP):
NameError: name 'ICMP' is not defined
```

if change:

```
 class Pinger(**ICMP**):
```

to

```
class Pinger():

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping.py", line 54, in <module>
    reactor.listenICMP(0, Pinger())
  File "./txnet/reactor.py", line 21, in listenICMP
    p.startListening()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 102, in startListening
    self._connectToProtocol()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 123, in _connectToProtocol
    self.protocol.makeConnection(self)
AttributeError: Pinger instance has no attribute 'makeConnection'
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or not understand?

P.S. twisted 12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running `sandbox/ping.py`, then the exception you report doesn't make sense.  That file has this import near the beginning:

```
from txnet.icmp import ICMP, Packet, ECHO_REQUEST
```

This defines the `ICMP` name.  The `Pinger` class comes later, extending it.  I can successfully run this demo program (though it fails with an unrecognized message type when handling the response on my sytem).

Perhaps you have an old version of the code, or have modified it somehow, or are running a different `ping.py`?

Comment: if i run from main/sandbox:ImportError: No module named txnet.icmp . I copy ping.py to 1 level up to main folder

Comment: I pulled the latest master and I am still getting this error any ideas?

Comment: I don't really know what's wrong, sorry.  However, note the answer is over 4 years old now.  Perhaps txnet has introduced further incompatible changes that invalidate this answer.