# python code instead of a real file

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I have a program that i have wrote, internally i am using the Fping program in order to send pings to other computers, the Fping program needs to get a file that includes a list of IP address in order to get Fping to send pings automatically to a bunch of IP address.

Right now in my script i am creating a file on the disk then call Fping to use that file, then i am deleting the file.

I would like to know if there is a way to create a file-like object that is acting as a file, then i could call Fping to use that object instead of a real file.

I am using Python 3, and [Fping for Windows](http://www.kwakkelflap.com/fping.html).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fping` can read in the list of machines from standard input (see details in the [man page](http://fping.sourceforge.net/man/)) you simply need to write the addresses to standard input. The [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) can provide some ways to write data to standard input, but if all the data is known at the start, a (somewhat tacky) way to do this is to add `echo` to your command.

```
echo 4.2.2.1 www.google.com www.yahoo.co.uk | fping
```

Comment: I am using Fping for Windows, can i assume that it has the ability to read a list of IPs from the stdin too ?

Comment: Hrm, if it is the same project, then yes, but if it is supplied by a different group, then maybe not. Try it and see? (If it isn't, please respond again, and I can delete my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use Fping? You could ping directly from python.

[Ping a site in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)