# How to eliminate standard output of subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ping

When i did something in Python as:

```
ping = subprocess.Popen("ping -n 1 %s" %ip, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

it is always to print out to screen:

```
(subprocess.Popen object at 0x.... )
```

It's a bit annoying for me. Do you know how to avoid that std output ?

Comment: how do you run it? It shouldn't produce such output

Comment: Running `ping = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '127.0.0.1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` produces no output.

Comment: see here [how to ping multiple hosts using subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279)

Comment: I guess you are getting away with calling Popen wrongly because your shell is brain dead

Comment: you have a `print` statement printing your `ping` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the stdout from the process by printing the `ping` variable in your example. That is incorrect usage of `subprocess.Popen` objects. In order to correctly use `subprocess.Popen` this is what you would write:

```
ping_process = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# This will block until ping exits
stdout = ping_process.stdout.read()
print stdout
```

I also changed the arguments you used for ping because `-n` is an invalid argument on my machines implementation.