# Python subprocess call efficiency

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a python program which pings devices and reports online/offline status and latency. Right now it is working fine but whenever there are devices offline or not responding the output hangs for about 5 seconds.

My question is can I either ping everything independently and not sequentially and/or can I set a time filter of some sort on the subprocess so that, if things aren't updated after ~100-200ms it moves on to the next?

Here is the relevant part of the code I am currently working on

```
for item in lines:
#remove whitespaces, etc from item.
hostname = item.rstrip()

#Run ping and return output to stdout.
#subprocess.Popen runs cmdline ping, pipes the output to stdout. .stdout.read() then reads that stream data and assigns it to the ping_response variable
ping_response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", hostname, "-n", '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
word = "Received = 1"
word2 = "Destination host unreachable."

#Regex for finding the time values and inputting them in to a list.
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=time[<=])\S+')
x = re.findall(p, ping_response)
if word2 in ping_response:
    print "Destination Unreachable"
elif word in ping_response:
    print "%s is online with latency of " % hostname +x[0]
else:
    print "%s is offlineOffline" % hostname
```

Comment: This would be a very good application for multithreading, because your program isn't CPU or I/O bound, but instead is waiting most of the time (on the network, or on a timeout). [Doug Hellmann's article on the `threading` module](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: @LukasGraf: [You don't need threads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279) here (though [they can be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321632/4279)); `Popen()` creates a separate process and returns immidiately without waiting for the child process to exit. You don't want 1000 threads/processes to ping 1000 hosts in parallel. Async. I/O could be used here (a `select`-like loop such as used in `twisted`, `asyncio`, `gevent` libraries).

Comment: related: [Multiple ping script in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12101239/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian *"You don't want 1000 threads/processes to ping 1000 hosts in parallel"* - that's exactly what you're doing in your `Popen()` multiple ping script though, no? I don't see any sort of pooling there. With threads you'd obviously use thread pooling like you did in your other example.

Comment: @LukasGraf: [the script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279) creates 100 processes, not 1000. If OP needs to ping thousands hosts concurrently then [async. io](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4868866/4279) should be considered (as well as [thread pooling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321632/4279)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is can I either ping everything independently and not sequentially

Sure.  There are a variety of solutions to that problem, including both the `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules.

> and/or can I set a time filter of some sort on the subprocess so that, if things aren't updated after ~100-200ms it moves on to the next?

You can actually set a timeout on `ping` itself, at least the Linux version, using the `-W` option:

```
   -W timeout
          Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only
          timeout in absence of any responses, otherwise  ping  waits  for
          two RTTs.
```

Answer (score 2):

`Ping` has a timeout feature which will help your script's efficiency.

```
-W waittime
             Time in milliseconds to wait for a reply for each packet sent.  If a reply arrives later, the packet
             is not printed as replied, but considered as replied when calculating statistics.
```

Also, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/200468/how-can-i-set-a-short-timeout-with-the-ping-command) are some other utilities to ping efficiently.