# python subprocess.popen ping fails after no response

Tags: python, subprocess, ping, popen

I have ping function below using subproces

```
def ping_sub1(a):
            with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
        for ip in a:
            result = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-w", "1", ip], stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
            if result:
                a.remove(ip)
    return a
```

I run with 'a' list below where 123.123.123.123 is not responsive. It looks like 
it's removed from list but then program stops...it works only fine if all addresses are responsive.

```
>>> a=['10.29.1.1', '123.123.123.123', '123.123.123.123', '10.29.21.208']
>>> pingtest4.ping_sub1(a)
['10.29.1.1', '123.123.123.123', '10.29.21.208']
>>> pingtest4.ping_sub1(a)
['10.29.1.1', '10.29.21.208']
>>> pingtest4.ping_sub1(a)
['10.29.1.1', '10.29.21.208']
>>>
```

Please advise

Comment: Don't modify a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Don't remove items from a list you are looping over; it will work if you loop in reverse or remove `ip` addresses *after* looping.

Comment: here's how you could [`ping` multiple hosts using `subprocess` module in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279)