# Getting input given to subprocess.Popen from stored subprocess.Popen object

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

If I have a list of `subprocess.Popen` objects, is there any way to tell what command was initially used when generating them?

Python 2.7

**Context:**
I have a list of various commands that fire off tests.  If one of the tests fails, a script cleans up the environment.  I would like to then retry those failed commands only.

**Note:** Commands below are for demonstration purposes only; those called in my prod code are more complex, but that is beside the point. If I can this to work, it will work with my prod cmds.

```
commands = [['nosetests', '-V'],
        ['nosetests', '--collect-only'],
        ['nosetests', '--with-id']
        ]

def cleanup_env():
    ...do things...

def run_in_parallel(cmds, retry):
    retry_tasks = []

    if not cmds:
        return

    def done(p):
        return p.poll() is not None

    def success(p):
        return p.returncode == 0

    def fail(p):
        if not retry:
            retry_tasks.append(p)
            print("{} failed, will need to retry.".format(retry_tasks))
        else:
            pass # if this is already a retry, we don't care, not going to retry again

    MAX_PARALLEL = 4
    processes = []

    while True:
        while cmds and len(processes) < MAX_PARALLEL:
            task = cmds.pop() # pop last cmd off the stack
            processes.append(subprocess.Popen(task))

        for p in processes:
            if done(p):
                if success(p):
                    processes.remove(p)
                else:
                    fail(p)
                    processes.remove(p)

        if not processes and not cmds:
            break

        else:
            time.sleep(0.05)

    return retry_tasks
```

Calling the above:

```
retry_list=run_in_parallel(commands, False)

if retry_list:
    cleanup_env()
    run_in_parallel(retry_list, True)
```

The first part works, but calling the retry doesn't because I'm passing a list of `subprocess.Popen` objects, rather than their initial input.

Hence the question, how do I get at the input of a `subprocess.Popoen` object?

Comment: unrelated: your `run_in_parallel()` is incorrect (don't remove items from a sequence during iteration; [use `break` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279)). [A simple way to keep the same number of parallel process is to use a thread pool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14533902/4279)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Popen.args` in Python 2.7. You could use a dictionary instead of a list for `processes` where keys are `Popen` instances and values are corressponding `Popen` parameters.