# Checking if subprocess started

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, subprocess

I have a program that starts four others and I want them to run simultaneously which I can do with `subprocess.Popen()` and I want to check if they started correctly. If not, do nothing and wait until the next time it gets called. I'm working on windows and this is what I have so far but I'm not positive this works the way I think it will and I don't know how to test it other than sit around and hope it fails but continues on. Can someone tell me if this will work or not and if not why?

```
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime

while 1:

    Day = time.strftime('%d')
    Month = time.strftime('%m')
    Year = time.strftime('%Y')  #if conditions are just right(the day changes before month and year are calculated) then the dates could get off (highly unlikely)
    start = time.clock()
    try:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'C:/Users/tnabrelsfo/Documents/Programs/strippers/TransmitterStrip.py'], stdout=None)
    except OSError:
        print('Error with Transmitter')
    try:
        p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'C:/Users/tnabrelsfo/Documents/Programs/strippers/ReceiverStrip.py'], stdout=None)
    except OSError:
        print('Error with Receiver')
    try:
        p3 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'C:/Users/tnabrelsfo/Documents/Programs/strippers/UIDStrip.py'], stdout=None)
    except OSError:
        print('Error with UID')
    try:
        p4 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'C:/Users/tnabrelsfo/Documents/Programs/strippers/BlueStripper.py'], stdout=None)
    except OSError:
        print('Error with Blue')


    p1.wait()
    p2.wait()
    p3.wait()
    p4.wait()
    print('Duration: %.2f' % (time.clock()-start))
    print('\n' + str(datetime.now()) + '\n')
    print('Done with run')

    for x in range(301):
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The process may start fine, but exit with an error. So while `p1.wait()` is waiting, one of the other processes may have died. Do you need immediate feedback in that case?

Comment: @eryksun no I do not need immediate feedback. I just need the program to not die if one of the child processes fails.

Comment: If `stdout=None` is an attempt to discard the output then use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` instead on Python 3 (same for `stderr`).

Comment: here's [how you could run multiple processes in parallel and check their exit statuses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279)

Comment: how exactly does your parent script die? (it shouldn't even if  child scripts fail)

Comment: Have you considered [to import the modules and calling the corresponding functions instead of using `subprocess` here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30165768/4279)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am using 2.7 and the output is working the way I want. Also when the child doesn't execute correctly it is throwing errors and kills everything for some reason and yes I thought about just calling them as functions but I need them to run in parallel and to be able to wait on them to finish.

Comment: Don't use PIPE unless you consume the pipe otherwise your child process may hang. [To discard output on Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279). Update your question and provide the full traceback that demonstrates how you think an error in a child process kills the parent.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I noticed PIPE was making it hang and I don't remember what the error was but it was definitely killing my parent process. I used the first link you provided which makes the most sense to me. I'm not sure what was causing the errors in the first place.