# how do i ping all the servers at once python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ping

```
import pyping

server = ["jeff", "bob", "dave", "ryan", "drew"]

for i in server:
    online = 1
    try:
        result = pyping.ping(i)
        online = result.ret_code
        if len(i) > 7:
            print("|\tServer: "+ i +"\tIp: "+ result.destination_ip +"\tTime: "+ result.avg_rtt +"\t |")
        else:
            print("|\tServer: "+ i +"\t\tIp: "+ result.destination_ip +"\tTime: "+ result.avg_rtt +"\t |")

    except:
        print("|\tServer: "+ i +" Returned: OFFLINE!!!\t\t\t\t |")
```

please help me ping all of the servers at the same time to make it quicker

Comment: [Multiple ping script in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12101239/4279)

Comment: What about using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: The subprocess script would do, however as this is I/O operation my approach would use Thread(s). I think some of the examples on the web that show how to deal with multiple threads (and use beautifulsoup) can be adapted to do exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import threading

def worker(i):
    online = 1
    try:
        result = pyping.ping(i)
        online = result.ret_code
        if len(i) > 7:
            print("|\tServer: "+ i +"\tIp: "+ result.destination_ip +"\tTime: "+ result.avg_rtt +"\t |")
        else:
            print("|\tServer: "+ i +"\t\tIp: "+ result.destination_ip +"\tTime: "+ result.avg_rtt +"\t |")

    except:
        print("|\tServer: "+ i +" Returned: OFFLINE!!!\t\t\t\t |")

server = ["jeff", "bob", "dave", "ryan", "drew"]

for i in server:
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```