# Is there a quick way to know the status of another computer?

Tags: python, windows, ping

I need to know the status of ten computers.

Trying to use "PING",I get the info in ten seconds.

I want a more quick way to get this info in **Windows7 64**.

code:

```
from platform import system as system_name # Returns the system/OS name
from os import system as system_call       # Execute a shell command
def ping(host):

# Ping parameters as function of OS
parameters = "-n 1" if system_name().lower()=="windows" else "-c 1"

# Pinging
return system_call("ping " + parameters + " " + host) == 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if the machine disallows ping?

Comment: As an aside: aliasing `system` to `system_call` will confuse people reading your code -- `system` runs a shell command; it doesn't perform a system call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple ping script in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101239/multiple-ping-script-in-python)

Comment: https://github.com/Lingerhk/hacking_script/blob/master/net_attacking/icmp_ping_tool.py

I found it , it's fast!

Comment: What do you mean by "status"?

Comment: open or close  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with subprocess

```
import subprocess

def ping(host):

    # Ping parameters as function of OS
    parameters = "-n" if system_name().lower()=="windows" else "-c"

    # Pinging
    return subprocess.Popen(["ping", host, parameters, '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Comment: sorry,I forgot to tell you I'm windows.

Comment: @eason did you try it and didn't work? what error it gives to you?

Comment: [Error2] The system can not find the specified file

Comment: @cricket_007 Absolutely true, thank you so much, I updated

Comment: @eason I updated the answer, let me know if that work now :)