# Parsing ping output with Python

Tags: python, regex, ping

how would you parse the 'ping' output, looking like this:

```
root@m2m-probe1:~/M2M/src# ping -c 20 -q google.es
PING google.es (173.194.34.247) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.es ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19043ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 314.766/381.299/430.826/36.513 ms
```

with Python? The better I've found so far is:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('ping ' + host + " -c 5 -q  | egrep \"packet loss|rtt\"", shell=True)

match = re.search('([\d]*\.[\d]*)/([\d]*\.[\d]*)/([\d]*\.[\d]*)/([\d]*\.[\d]*)', output)

ping_min = match.group(1)
ping_avg = match.group(2)
ping_max = match.group(3)

match = re.search('(\d*)% packet loss', output)
pkt_loss = match.group(1)
```

it works, but I know it's far from being the best way of achieving it. Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ping a site in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python)

Comment: Actually the real purpouse of this question is to learn about regexp with Python... I'll be working a lot with them over the next weeks. I was looking for a single regexp to match both lines, packet loss & min/avg/max/jitter values. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

There's already a pure python module that does that https://github.com/gg/pingparser, however if you're looking to implement it for pedagogical purposes, use the pyparsing library. It's much better than regexps for parsing data.

Comment: I found pingparser just before asking here, but it does not support packet loss and it's an important field for me. I'll try to modify pingparser to support it.

Comment: I've tried ping parser, and it's bombing out with Mac OS X ping formatting.  I don't see anything obvious breaking in the code...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not found of regex, probably because I don't use it enough....

```
output = subprocess.check_output('ping -c %s -W %s -t %s 8.8.8.8' % (self.numPings, (self.pingTimeout * 1000), self.maxWaitTime), shell=True)

output = output.split('\n')[-3:]
# -1 is a blank line, -3 & -2 contain the actual results

xmit_stats = output[0].split(",")
timing_stats = output[1].split("=")[1].split("/")

packet_loss = float(xmit_stats[2].split("%")[0])

ping_min = float(timing_stats[0])
ping_avg = float(timing_stats[1])
ping_max = float(timing_stats[2])
```