# How to make a ping client in Python socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I learn Python and as a practice decided to write a server for a network game "Backgammon". The question arose as to make sure that found in the queue apponet still online? How to send a ping and accept the answer? I'm trying to do it on line 71, but this is incorrect.

```
import pymongo, socket, threading, string, json, MySQLdb, random, time
stat = True
conn = {}
#gamers = {}
games = {}
diceroll = []
tempconn = {}

c = pymongo.Connection()
db = c.nardy
nru = db.notregusers
uwait = db.userwait

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, channel, details):
        self.channel = channel
        self.details = details
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def getUserId(self, data):
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        if json_data['t'] == 'n':
            print ' - User not register'
            if nru.find({'identuser':json_data['i'], 'platform':json_data['p']}).count() == 0:
                print ' - New user'
                count = nru.find().count();
                newid = count + 1;
                nru.save({'id':newid, 'identuser':json_data['i'], 'platform':json_data['p'], 'level':1})
                return nru.find_one({'id':newid})
            else:
               print ' - Old user'
               return nru.find_one({'identuser':json_data['i'], 'platform':json_data['p']})
        elif json_data['t'] == 'r':
            return 9999

    def mySQLConnect(self):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="", passwd="", db="", charset='utf8')
        return db

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.channel.recv(1024)
            try:
                json_data = json.loads(data)                
                comm = json_data['c']
                if comm == 'x':
                    if conn.has_key(gamer['level']) and self in conn[gamer['level']]:
                        conn[gamer['level']].remove(self)
                    self.channel.close()
                    break
                elif comm == 'h':
                    gamer = self.getUserId(data)
                    self.gamer = gamer
                elif comm == 'f':
                    lev = 0
                    findenemy = 1
                    while findenemy == 1:
                        if conn.has_key(gamer['level']):
                            lev = gamer['level']
                        elif conn.has_key((gamer['level'] - 1)):
                            lev = (gamer['level'] - 1)
                        elif conn.has_key((gamer['level'] + 1)):
                            lev = (gamer['level'] + 1)
                        if lev != 0:
                            if len(conn[lev]) > 0:
                                enemy = conn[lev].pop(0)
                                firsttime = time.time()
                                enemy.channel.send('{"o":"p"}')

                                while (firsttime + 30) > time.time() and findenemy == 1:
                                    if comm == 'k':
                                        findenemy = 0
                                        print ' - Ping enemy: ok'


                                if findenemy == 0:
                                    self.enemy = enemy
                                    gameid = str(self.gamer['id']) + '_' + str(self.enemy.gamer['id'])
                                    games[gameid] = {'dice':[], 'nextstep':0}
                                    vrag = self.enemy
                                    a = random.sample(range(1,7),2)
                                    self.channel.send('{"o":"s", "u":"' + str(a[0]) + '", "e":"' + str(a[1]) + '"}')
                                    vrag.channel.send('{"o":"s", "u":"' + str(a[1]) + '", "e":"' + str(a[0]) + '"}')
                                    if a[0] > a[1]:
                                        step = 1
                                        games[gameid]['nextstep'] = self.gamer['id']
                                        self.channel.send('{"o":"u"}')
                                        vrag.channel.send('{"o":"w"}')
                                    else:
                                        step = 2
                                        games[gameid]['nextstep'] = self.enemy.gamer['id']
                                        self.channel.send('{"o":"w"}')
                                        vrag.channel.send('{"o":"u"}')
                                    tempconn[self.enemy] = self
                            else:
                                conn[lev].append(self)
                                findenemy = 0
                                self.channel.send('{"o":"q"}')
                        else:
                            conn[gamer['level']] = [self]
                            self.channel.send('{"o":"q"}')
                elif comm == 'w':
                    if not hasattr(self, 'enemy'):
                        self.enemy = tempconn[self]
                        vrag = self.enemy
                        gameid = str(self.enemy.gamer['id']) + '_' + str(self.gamer['id'])
                    self.channel.send('{"o":"o"}')
                elif comm == 'r' and games[gameid]['nextstep'] == self.gamer['id']:
                    dice = []
                    dice.append(self.gamer['id'])
                    dice.append(random.randint(1,6))
                    dice.append(random.randint(1,6))
                    games[gameid]['dice'].append(dice)
                    self.channel.send('{"o":"r", "f":"' + str(dice[1]) + '", "s":"' + str(dice[2]) + '"}')
                    vrag.channel.send('{"o":"r", "f":"' + str(dice[1]) + '", "s":"' + str(dice[2]) + '"}')
                    games[gameid]['nextstep'] = self.enemy.gamer['id']
                elif comm == 'r' and games[gameid]['nextstep'] != self.gamer['id']:
                    self.channel.send('{"o":"w"}')
                elif comm == 'm' and 't' in json_data:
                    self.channel.send('{"o":"y", "t":"' + str(json_data['text']) + '"}')
                    vrag.channel.send('{"o":"e", "t":"' + str(json_data['text']) + '"}')
                elif comm == 's':
                    self.channel.send('{"o":"g", "countgame":"' + str(len(games)) + '"}')
                elif comm == 'q' and 's' in json_data and 'e' in json_data:
                    print " - Player step"
                elif comm == 'b' and self in conn[gamer['level']]:
                    conn[gamer['level']].remove(self)

            except ValueError:
                continue
        print 'Closed connection:', self.details[0]

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8088))
server.listen(5)

while stat:
    channel, details = server.accept()
    ClientThread(channel, details).start()
```

Perhaps, in addition to answering the question, you give me some recommendations ...

Comment: what do you want to ping?

Comment: It is not clear what does "ping" means in the context of your question. Here's related to the title of your question link: [Ping a site in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/316866/4279)

Comment: At the moment when the player finds a rival in the queue, you must send a message to this opponent. It must respond to this message. If you answered, so he is still online. Then you can continue to work on creating a game room.

Comment: Is your question how do I send a request (using tcp socket) and how do I read a response (both request/response may use an application protocol of your choosing)? *"but this is incorrect."* is not very informative. You could start with a minimal echo client/server and grow it into a [minimal complete code example that demonstrates your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear whether you are interested in how to call `.recv()` on a blocking socket with a short timeout *or* how to design the structure of your networking code and the game in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you to send out a ping and get response.

1. Use `scapy`. Use `sendp` function to send a ping and get response.
2. Use `os.system` to invoke command line to send a ping and get response. Like `os.system('ping 127.0.0.1')`

Hope it helps.:)