# Python-ping module not found after installation

Tags: python, module, pip, ping

I tried to install [python-ping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ping/2011.10.17.376a019) with `pip` but I was getting:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-ping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-ping (from versions: 2011.10.12.11fc9f7, 2011.10.12.1d8e600, 2011.10.13.12050a5, 2011.10.17.376a019)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for python-ping
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

So I installed it with `pip install --pre python-ping` and the installation outputted:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-ping
  Downloading python-ping-2011.10.17.376a019.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-8QnXqD/python-ping/setup.py) egg_info for package python-ping

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: python-ping
  Running setup.py install for python-ping
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/ping.py from 644 to 755

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory '*'
    changing mode of /usr/bin/ping.py to 755
Successfully installed python-ping
Cleaning up...
```

Despite the warnings I assumed it was successful.

I then tried to import the ping module to give it a test, copy-pasting the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python), but I'm getting:

```
ImportError: No module named ping
```

First time I encounter any problems installing a module with `pip`. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can always use subprocess to ping and forget about using  library

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It wouldn't be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the `setup.py` of the package of `python-ping`, it does not install a module, but instead installs a script (which should be installed in your python scripts folder).  You should invoke the script directly, eg: `ping.py www.google.com`. If this does not work, make sure your path is set to include the python scripts folder on your system.

If you'd prefer a module solution, check out `ping` on pypi, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping/0.2